# infinitude of primes with primitive pythagorean triple variables

Tags: prime-numbers

I just want to share what I found, I don't know if this is something useful or worth knowing:

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a primitive pythagorean triple, odd $y$, then there are infinitely many primes of the form:
$(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)/(z+x)(z+y) - (z-y)/2$

Comment: A few numeric example would most certainly improve this question.

Comment: BTW, if this expression also yields infinitely many non-primes (let alone, infinitely many non-integers), then I doubt if it is really "worth" anything.

Comment: try the triple (3,4,5) this gives the prime 2.

Comment: the result is always an integer

Comment: @jevie but $y$ is odd? Maybe $(4,3,5)$?

Comment: The triple $(3,4,5)$ is only a single example (and a very trivial one). You must have found a few more, to come up with this conjecture. Also - are there also infinitely many cases of non-primes? If so, then just FYI, by Dirichlet theorem, every 1st degree polynomial whose coefficients are coprimes yields infinitely many primes (and obviously infinitely many non-primes)... So although your expression is not a 1st degree polynomial (and not even a single-variable polynomial), I doubt that it contributes anything.

Comment: @barak manos yea I also think its not raeally worth anything just want to share if something could be deduced from the statement, etc.

Comment: Well, then I suggest that you by the least share some of the information that has led you to this conjecture. As I've already mentioned, a few numeric examples might be very useful for others to observe some sort of pattern that makes this expression yields infinitely many primes.

Comment: BTW, your expression gives $242.5$ for $x=3,y=4,z=5$. In order for it to give a value closer to $2$, you need to put $(z+x)(z+y)$ in parenthesis. And if you do that, then it gives $2.5$. That's not even an integer. So it sounds to make like you haven't done any research whatsoever, but rather tried only a single numeric example, and probably without even bothering to make sure that the result is correct (I guess you've used integer division instead of floating-point division).

Comment: @barak manos precisely correct. I noticed it also.

Comment: @juniven: And in addition, OP says "odd $y$" in the question, then gives an example with an even $y$ in the comment ($4$)... Feels like not much thought was put into all this...

Comment: @barak manos I asked him already, see my comment

Comment: @juniven: I think that the expression doesn't even yield an integer value for most Pythagorean triplets. And to make it ($6$ times) worse - no matter how you permute them!!!

Comment: I think you dont get my equation, the result is always an integer that is a sum of two squares

Comment: i dont know to to write the equation in a latex

Comment: first add the cubes of x, y and z. then divide the result by z+x and by z+y, then subtract the result by z-y/2

Comment: example:  (4,3,5), 4^3 + 3^3 + 5^3 = 216, z+x=9, z+y=8. divide 216 by 8x9=72, the result is 3. subtract (z-y)/2=(5-3)/2=1 will give 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, using the well-known parametrization of primitive Pythagorean triples
$$
x=2rs,\, y=r^2-s^2,\, z=r^2+s^2
$$
where $r>s>0$ are coprime and of opposite parity, we obtain the simplification
$$
\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{(x+z) (y+z)}-\frac{z-y}{2} = (r-s)^2+s^2.
$$
And every prime congruent to $1$ (mod $4$), as well as the prime $2$, can be written in this form by a theorem of Fermat.

Comment: btw how do you write a fraction form of the equation in latex?

Comment: @jevie: Using \frac{x}{y} with a dollar sign on each side. But I would generally recommend that you input LaTex into your favorite search engine and read a little. It's not too difficult.